# Facebook swf embed works only for selected domains

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-opengraph

Since about a week or two the facebook swf embed feature stopped working for my website. I realized that it stopped working for a few websites but was still working for soundcloud.com. After doing some research i was able to pinpoint the issue to a single open graph tag.

A website containing the following does seam to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="music.song" property="og:type">
<meta content="http://venc.pl/test.html" property="og:url">
<meta content="Asd - Keygen Music" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000026602093-dp518o-t500x500.jpg?16b9957" property="og:image">
<meta content="Listen to Asd / Asd - Keygen Music | Explore the largest community of artists, bands, podcasters and creators of music &amp; audio." property="og:description">
<meta content="SoundCloud" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="video" name="medium">
<meta content="98" property="og:video:height">
<meta content="460" property="og:video:width">
<meta content="application/x-shockwave-flash" property="og:video:type">
<meta content="http://player.soundcloud.com/player2.swf" property="og:video">
</head></html>
```

But the following does not

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="music.song" property="og:type">
<meta content="http://venc.pl/test2.html" property="og:url">
<meta content="Asd - Keygen Music" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000026602093-dp518o-t500x500.jpg?16b9957" property="og:image">
<meta content="Listen to Asd / Asd - Keygen Music | Explore the largest community of artists, bands, podcasters and creators of music &amp; audio." property="og:description">
<meta content="SoundCloud" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="video" name="medium">
<meta content="98" property="og:video:height">
<meta content="460" property="og:video:width">
<meta content="application/x-shockwave-flash" property="og:video:type">
<meta content="http://venc.pl/player.swf" property="og:video">
</head></html>
```

So it basically boils down to changes in the domain presented in the og:video tag (). 
There used to be a whitelist of websites enabled to embed swf on facebook a few years ago. The idea was dropped but I think that Facebook just got back to it.

How can I get in touch with facebook to resolve this issue? If a whitelisting is needed how do I ask for being whitelisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to this is that the swf file needs to be on an https link (see [how to share a video from my website on facebook like youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903547/how-to-share-a-video-from-my-website-on-facebook-like-youtube))

Comment: Yes that was the case. Still for soundcloud embeding using http did work (at least back then).