# how to share a video from my website on facebook like youtube

Tags: facebook, html, video, youtube, embed

I have a website that has a HTML5 video player.

I want to share the link ( ex: http://site.com/video/example-2 ) on facebook and one the users click on the image of that post on the facebook it starts playing the video there.

Just like youtube videos and vimeo videos.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I have a website that has a HTML5 video player.

You want to find a good SWF (*.SWF) video player that can stream video from `url={video_Hot_link}` (pass `URL` parameter to the `SWF` player)

Now after you got your SWF player ready for streaming some videos add [Facebook Open Graph](http://ogp.me)
to your `<head>` tag like below:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video"> <!-- site/page type more information http://ogp.me/ -->
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"> <!-- you need this because your player is a SWF player -->
<meta property="og:video:width" content="Width in Pixels"> <!-- player width -->
<meta property="og:video:height" content="Height in Pixels"> <!-- player height -->
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/{path_to}/{swf_player}.swf?url={video_soure}"> <!-- You will need to echo/print the video source (*.mp4) with server-side code -->
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/{path_to}/{swf_player}.swf?url={video_soure}"> <!-- required for users whom use SSL (actually Facebook forces everyone to use SSL so you're required to use og:video:secure_url) so get a one -->
```

Additionally, you need to add the following prefix to `<html>` likeso

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Comment: and just for the record i needed to put also 'xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"' on my HTML tag.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Facebook merely displays the eventual og:image. When this is not present it just links to page that was initially posted. It does not seem to take care about the SWF URL, although the scraping debug tool says everything is fine with my OpenGraph metatags. Do I need to have a facebook app ID included too or will it work without that?

Comment: No, `Meta OG` tags doesn't require an `APP_ID` or a SDK to be installed, can you share your url?

Comment: @AdamAzad OK I figured out the issue was that I had to use an HTTPS URL for the SWF. Otherwise Facebook will not embed the URL (at least when accessed via HTTPS)! So now it works :)I posted an edit to your answer in order to make this more clear.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Stephane was having - when I share a link, I don't get the flash I want embedded. I have, however, provided https. Here's the lint of the URL I'm using: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fzzzz.io%2Fstatic%2Fmusic%2Ftest.html . Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Does the comment about "needing" to use a SWF player means that I cannot use a standard HTML5 <video> tag with a straight source attribute pointing to the MP4 file?

Comment: @EagertoLearn I didn't mention anything about `<body>` tag nor HTML5 `<video>` tag, however you're free to use SWF player or `<video>` but for Facebook Open Graph (`<meta>` within `<head>`) you need a Flash player.

Comment: @AdamAzad ...I'm still confuse in what way I will post to my wall. I see the META above, and I assume you place that on the <Head> tag somewhere but ..what's the action to actually POST to Facebook?

Comment: @AdamAzad or is my URL page typed by the actual user within the Facebook Status edit box?

Comment: You post your URL which has those `meta` tags to Facebook sharer or status update box

Comment: Ok ...my need is different. I have a site that has a video and I need a way to have a button on my website that will POST that video on the user's Facebook Account. Do you know the right way to achieve that?

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions (including those comments) and did not succeed... can anyone help me? my website url (which I share) http://www.wise-event.co.il

Comment: Can anyone suggest a good swf player which I can use for playback of an mp4 video (h.264 + aac audio). Preferably a free alternative. In urgent need of it. Thanks..

Comment: @SFDeveloper are you able to find good solution for that, I have same issue

Comment: @zeroonnet Is it possible that you can share your solution with us? I am having the same issue

Comment: @AdamAzad Can you please provide the full working tutorial. That would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook no longer permits inline playback for third party players. Vimeo even mentions this [in their documentation](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007867647-Optimizing-your-website-for-posting-to-social-platforms).

Moving forward you will need to use Facebook's own video hosting platform if you want to have videos play inline in the newsfeed.

Comment: Hi, do have any official information about this? I'm in need of a way (the new way) to publish small video's in Facebook feeds and information on how to do that is at most sketchy. thanks

Comment: I have a hard time finding official documentation for this as well. From everything I've seen and heard Facebook only allows their own videos now.

Answer (score 0):

I also used og:video to share video but on debugging it on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ , it gives warning error The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: In my experience that warning comes up when using "name" and not "property" values in the meta tags.

Make sure to use <meta property="og:image"> and not <meta name="og:image">.