# How to share a video from website to facebook like how youtube do?

Tags: facebook

I have making a website which can play movie trailer. I hope the users can share the trailer in their facebook and play directly in facebook like how youtube do.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18903547/2151050) was asked 5 days ago, so you can
Follow [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050) it's exactly what you are looking for