# Embedded Youtube + Facebook Post

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, video, youtube

I have a youtube video embedded on my personal blog that I would like to post to facebook and allow people to watch the video straight from their facebook feed.

However, if I link the blog entry via facebook by entering http://nickbewley.com/music/juicy-j/ , facebook pulls this header image from my site:

```
<a href="/">
   <img src="http://www.nickbewley.com/static/img/logo.png">
</a>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Facebook pulls wrong asset]

Rather, I want facebook to pull the embedded youtube video and allow users to play the video directly from their facebook feed..

I am using an iframe currently, but have tried to use the old embed code as well, but to no avail as of yet.

I want to be able to share music from my blog directly to facebook, and allow users to watch the content within their news feed. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you share the YouTube link directly with Facebook instead of your website it should work, but I have a feeling that's not exactly what you are wanting.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Facebook's [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)?

Comment: @photodow yes i am familiar with graph api. But how could i use it to post a status update linking to my personal blog allowing end users to play the youtube video directly from the status update?

Comment: Follow this answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand how Facebook's Open Graphs work is by `meta` tags in your `head` that tells Facebook how to read/display the content on your page when shared. A snippet of YouTube's Open Graph `meta` looks like the following.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/9bZkp7q19f0?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="1080">
```

Here's a couple resources I was able to come up with that might provide helpful for you:

[Creating & Defining Object Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types/)

[Set Up your Website to Control Images & Text in Facebook Status Update Links](https://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/set-up-your-website-to-control-images-text-in-facebook-status-update-links/10150320031290844)

[video.movie object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/video.movie) - Check out the very bottom of the page and click it.

Let me know how it goes!