# Share audio to Facebook, making it playable inline

Tags: facebook, audio, facebook-opengraph

I have an online service where users make their own sounds. I want users to be able to share the sounds to facebook, making them playable in the feed.

If you share a soundcloud sound, it will be playable inline, but sharing a mp3 URL doesn't make it playable inline in the feed.

Is there any solution for this or do I need to upload the sounds to soundcloud and share from their API?

Up until about 2011 posting a mp3 URL to facebook would make it playable.

Comment: Soundscloud takes advantage of `og:video` to play the sound while sharing an `*.mp3` file as attachment wont make it playable on Facebook news feed (it was working before 2012) but it doesn't now for more information about how to make a mp3 playable in Newfeed you can follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050) it works for both videos and audios (mp3)