# Embed video webapp in Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

I have an app which displays an overlay over a chromeless Youtube video (or html5 video with sources from my server) with my own controls and functions. I would like to embed this app into Facebook posts the same way Youtube videos get embedded. Is this possible with the current Graph API, or is this limited only to Youtube?

Comment: Follow my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050

Comment: I'm linking more than just a player, it will have some overlays written in Javascript and HTML. Is there any way to do this with an HTML player rather than a Flash player?

Comment: Currently Facebook allows Flash content to be embedded for regular Website owners, while Facebook allows sounds from Soundcloud to have their own HTML5 valid tags within the post if you seen them later