# Facebook sharing button(include video in post)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website which i want to share via a facebook sharing button. The post needs to have the websites url as the link, but i do want to show a video in the post as well(as the thumbnail). I've made several  tags, but i cant seem to find a way to add a link to a youtube video.

It is even possible?

**Current code:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is my description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/Content/images/mobile.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://randomsite.yy"/>

<a class="resGreen" id="facebookSharer" style="display: none">
  <input type="button" class="whiteboxes" id="tipFriend" value="Post to a friend" />
</a>
```

After a search done by the user, i need to change the href for the sharebutton:

```
$('#facebookSharer').attr('href', 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?mode=friend&p[url]=http://randomsite.yy%2F' + inputName.replace(".no", ""));
```

Alternative:

I could just link to the youtube in the facebookpost, and have a anchor to the website in the description. Can i add a anchor href in the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer will help you, [how to share a video from my website on facebook like youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050) 
and you can replace the `og:video` content with the one from your YouTube video source for example:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/i2lUlz74Ng4?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
```

> Can i add a anchor href in the description?

the `description` field doesn't accept and/or allow any HTML tag including the anchor `<a>`

Comment: Getting approval for Twitter Card Player is rare so this is one case where Facebook may actually be easier for the little guy to work with than Twitter. FYI

Comment: Pardon? How did Twitter get into this?

Comment: Twitter is better, that's how. :-) Plus once you have one share button, you inevidably get asked for another one. So I'm always thinking how do I do this in Twitter too or Google+ or Pinterest and in this instance Facebook might be easiest.

Comment: Eh, okey. That being said, the market our business is trying to reach is on facebook, and not on twitter. Thats why this is what im trying to accomplish. I have however worked with twitter api in other projects.

Comment: When using this tag, i do see the play icon in the sharepost. When i click the playicon, it does not play the video, but it becomes a white area where nothing happens.