# How to use Open Graph to include a .swf video in a post to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want there to be an attached video file (in .swf form) to a post on facebook.

Their documentation on Open Graph is very confusing, and everything on the web seems outdated and does not work.

Say my website is http://example.com, and my video file is at http://example.com/player.swf, what meta tags do I need on my page to have the file included in the post?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050