# How to enable share video on facebook from my website

Tags: javascript, css, html, facebook

I have a website with HTML5 videos. I wanted to make a button for each video to share on facebook.

```
<video controls style="width:970px;">
     <source src="videos/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videos/video1.webm" type="video/webm">

      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you searched something?

Comment: I did. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903547/how-to-share-a-video-from-my-website-on-facebook-like-youtube) but I have no idea what he means by "video player that can stream video".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an anchor tag

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://yoursite.com/video_url">Share</a>
```

and style it with CSS.