# Share my website with Video instead of Image on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I looked on [how to share a video from my website on facebook like youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903547/how-to-share-a-video-from-my-website-on-facebook-like-youtube)
And comment there but no answer

My web site is www.wise-event.co.il and my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Wise Event - הדרך החכמה לניהול הערב" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Wise Event - ניהול אירועים ומוזמנים בסמרטפון" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />     
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="281" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="500" />        
<meta property="og:video" content="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=97653968" />  
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=97653968">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.wise-event.co.il/Content/img/WE/logo-final.png" />        
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.wise-event.co.il" />
<meta property="og:description" 
    content="אנו גאים להציג את מערכת Wise Event, המספקת נתונים לפני, בזמן ואחרי האירוע אודות האורחים, יוצרת מאגר לקוחות, ומנהלת את זרימת הקהל פנימה. " />       
<meta name="author" content="Wise Event">
```

tried:

- regular url supplied by vimeo... no luck
- debug it using the facebook developer debugger - no warnings

Why is it still brings the image instead of the video?

Comment: As an initial note, which may very well be the problem: your video URLs are redirected to a much longer URL, hosted by a different domain. Try linking directly to the video?

Comment: But the video is not hosted on my domain. Not sure what do u suggest? redirect from my domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your code works as shown on the Facebook object debugger : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.wise-event.co.il

The last part says it's a video with the good attributes of the video. The reason you think there is an error is because the Share Preview doesn't show a video, but if you try to actually share your url you can see the video as show here :

[image: Video Sharing Example]

Comment: I tried with a post on my profile, it only shows the picture

Comment: Have you tried going on this url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.wise-event.co.il , then click "Fetch new scrape information". It should work after if you try to post the url on your profile.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in facebook. It works, but I didn't changed nothing... Thanks anyway. I gave u the bounty award :)