# Can we make ajax requests on a FB embedded player

Tags: facebook, flash

I have a js player on which I have added interactivity. It was pretty easy since I used the HTML5 video element.
I was trying to include this player on my FB page but i know we need a swf player which is flash.
[how to share a video from my website on facebook like youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903547/how-to-share-a-video-from-my-website-on-facebook-like-youtube/18903890#18903890)

I want to know if we can make ajax calls in the swf player when its on FB timeline?

Is there an open source swf player that I can use to extend its functionality?

Comment: That would be a huge security issue IMHO...

Comment: So FB would not allow to do so? and how does youtube do it then? How can they have dynamic elements in their player

Comment: You asked about AJAX....

Comment: They have most likely that integrated within their Flash player directly. If it needs to make any additional requests to get “dynamic” data (whatever you think that means in this instance), then they have their Flash player make that request directly.

Comment: Yes, thats right. i wanted to know if we can do such requests from the flash player. And do you know about any open source flash player that i can extend?