# Share video to Facebook

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api, video, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to share a self host video to Facebook, currently I share a link to the Facebook where the video resides on but I want to change it to share the actual video.

In below code it will share video if its not an image

I am new to Facebook development.

This is what I currently have:

```
 @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(galleryNumber))
 {
    <div class="share-btns facebook">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@Url.Action("GalleryItem", "Client", new { itemHash = Model.SelectedItem.UrlHash, mobileNumber = galleryNumber }, "http")" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '@String.Format("Content Sharing - {0} - {1}",clientName, campaignName)', 'Facebook', '@String.Format("/{0}::/{1}", Model.UrlHash, Model.SelectedItem.UrlHash)']);return true;">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/spacer.gif")" alt="" width="82" height="82" />
        </a>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="share-btns facebook">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@Url.Action("Item", "Client", new { itemHash = Model.SelectedItem.UrlHash }, "http")" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '@String.Format("Content Sharing - {0} - {1}",clientName, campaignName)', 'Facebook', '@String.Format("/{0}::/{1}", Model.UrlHash, Model.SelectedItem.UrlHash)']);return true;">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/spacer.gif")" alt="" width="82" height="82" />
        </a>
    </div>
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903547/how-to-share-a-video-from-my-website-on-facebook-like-youtube/18903890#18903890) I need a .swf player then the video will be shared to Facebook.

Can anyone point me into the right direction for SWF player that will work on Facebook?

Comment: What URL are you sharing?

Comment: This is the link to the video on a site - http://www.mobflashing.co.za/ms/Absolut/i/kxgqpgzc
I want to share that video

Comment: Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=mobflashing.co.za%2Fms%2FAbsolut%2Fi%2Fkxgqpgzc . You need to put og:video on that page. And it needs to be a https url to the mp4 file

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for that! Do I need to remove the sharer.php link?

Comment: @WizKid I tested the code it still share the link to the site and not the actual video. Any suggestions?

Comment: og:video:type should be video/mp4 not video/MP4 and the secure url needs to be https (not http).